# Location of Firefox throbber/spinner image

Tags: image, firefox, mozilla, spinner, throbber

I'm trying to locate the "throbber" (or "spinner") image used in the Firefox 3.6x chrome to show that a request is being processed:

[Firefox throbber http://i49.tinypic.com/kd7bth.png](http://i49.tinypic.com/kd7bth.png)

I'm not familiar with the source code structure for Firefox, and a simple search hasn't yielded the answer.

Does anyone know which file I'm looking for? (E.g. can you provide a link to the file in the [Mercurial repository](http://hg.mozilla.org), or tell me how to find it?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your Firefox installation it's inside chrome/classic.jar, the path is: skin/classic/global/media/throbber.png

I'm not sure where it is in the Mozilla repository though.

Here's some info on how to customize it: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Throbber_URL

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.

It's within the chrome/classic.jar at: skin/classic/global/icons/loading_16.png

On Linux, my classic.jar was located at: /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.3/chrome/classic.jar